# Define a storyboard that could switch between views at runtime

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I would like to implement a simple UI which has one switch button, when switch is turned on the app shows one view, when turned off shows another view. (There is also an main button at the bottom which should always be visible no matter which `UIView` is shown)

I am thinking on storyboard, I use one `UIVIewController`, then define two `UIView` components each represent one view.

[image]

So, in short, I would like to show different UIViews at runtime between the *switch button* and the *Main button*.

But I get stuck, I am not sure how to show one of the `UIView` by default with my planned solution above. (Probably I am not sure whether it is correct way to do what I want to achieve.) Could someone please guide me a bit?

Comment: What does these two views contain? I think you can create views in the view controller itself and hide/show depending on switch state.

Comment: @hardik parmar, Each UIView contains different layout of different UI elements. Thanks, but if I do what you suggested, the view controller would be a mess of everything. I would try to make it be more organized, that's why I splited to two UIViews

Comment: Have you tried using container views? You can drag them into the storyboard from the library and then create outlets for them just like a regular `UIView`, `UISwitch`, etc — so they can be easily hidden. They are connected to another view controller via segue and should show that view controller's content.

Comment: There already is a solution for that kind of UI, the UITabBarController in your case with 2 tabs. You just need to modify the design of the TabBar.https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller

Comment: @LoVo but I don't need tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Within a storyboard you could add two container views. These are basically UIViewController added as children. Based on the switch, you could hide/show with the isHidden parameter one or the other.

[image: You should use this element twice]

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 different approaches:

1. Swap views: this can be done easily by using `UIView` animation, for instance this [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622562-transition) `transition(from:to:duration:options:completion:)`
2. Use contentment view controller API as already said by Wesley
   While the first one will do the trick, if your views have pretty different behaviors and business logic is better to use 2 different view controllers and use a container view. For more info click [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/containment-view-controller/) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html).